# XSRF token mismatch

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I am trying to handle a form submission via a custom controller in the admin section

This is my test controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/" + TempController.SECTION_KEY)
public class TempController extends AdminAbstractController {
    protected static final String SECTION_KEY = "test2";

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws Exception {
        // This is expected by the modules/emptyContainer template, this is a custom template that gets included into the body
        model.addAttribute("customView", "views/test2");
        ShippingEntity shp=new ShippingEntity();
        model.addAttribute("shipping",shp);
        // ensure navigation gets set up correctly
        setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);

        // gets the scaffolding set up to display the template from the customView attribute above
        return "modules/emptyContainer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,@ModelAttribute ShippingEntity shp) throws Exception {
        // This is expected by the modules/emptyContainer template, this is a custom template that gets included into the body
        model.addAttribute("customView", "views/test2");
        System.out.println(shp.getLink());
        System.out.println(shp.getTrackingNumber());
        model.addAttribute("shipping",shp);
        // ensure navigation gets set up correctly
        setModelAttributes(model, SECTION_KEY);

        // gets the scaffolding set up to display the template from the customView attribute above
        return "modules/emptyContainer";
    }


}
```

And this is the view template :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
           <form action="#" th:action="@{/test2}" th:object="${shipping}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{trackingNumber}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{link}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I submit the values I get the error:

XSRF token mismatch (null). Session may be expired

I understand that this has to do with security issues however I can't find a way to make it work.

Any tips how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was simpler than I thought, maybe it will help someone in the future.

Just change `<form> </form>` to `<blc:form></blc:form>`